# Sum Up all Numbers before and after an operator Sign in a String user input

Tags: kotlin

i am new to programming and starting up with kotlin .  i've been  stuck on this problem for a few days and i really need some assistance . i am trying to read a user input of Strings in a format like this   `3 + 2 + 1`, go through the String and wherever there is an operator , add up the numbers before and after the operator sign . so the above `3 + 2 + 1` should output `6`.
Here's a snippet of my code

```
fun main() {
val userInput = readLine()!!.split(" ")
var sum = 0
for (i in 0 until userInput.size) {
    if (userInput.get(i) == "+"){
        sum += userInput.get(i-1).toInt() + userInput.get(i+1).toInt()
    }

}
println(sum )
```

}

my code works until the point of adding up the numbers . it repeats the next number after the operator , so using the above example of `3 + 2 + 1`  it outputs `8` thus `3 + 2 + 2 + 1`. I'm so confused and don't know how to go about this .

Comment: Do the white spaces actually matter ? is there another authorized character than `+` between numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your code is that for each "+" encountered, it adds the sum of the numbers left and right of the "+" to the `sum`. For the example "1 + 2 + 3", here's what is happening:

1. Starting `sum` is 0.
2. At first "+", add 1 + 2 to `sum`, so now `sum` is 3.
3. At second "+", add 2 + 3 to `sum`, so now the `sum` is 3 + 5 = 8.

So you are adding all the middle numbers to the total twice, because they each appear next to two operators.

One way to do this is start with the first number as your `sum`. Then add only the number to the right of each "+", so numbers are only counted once.

```
fun main() {
    val userInput = readLine()!!.split(" ")
    var sum = userInput[0].toInt()

    for (i in userInput.indices) {
        if (userInput[i] == "+") {
            sum += userInput[i + 1].toInt()
        }
    }

    println(sum)
}
```

Comment: This made so much sense. I actually got it to work with  your explanation . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try not to increment the sum value each time, but rewrite the last number which was participated in sum. Just like that:

You have the case: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`

1. Split them
2. Now you have the array `[1, +, 2, +, 3, +, 4]`
3. Then you iterate this array, stuck with the first plus and sum the values.
4. Rewrite the second summed value with your sum.
5. Now you have new array `[1, +, 3, +, 3, +, 4]`
6. At the end of the loop, you will have this array `[1, +, 3, +, 6, +, 10]`
7. And your sum is the last element of the array

Answer (score 0):

```
sum += userInput.get(i-1).toInt() + userInput.get(i+1).toInt()
```

This is only valid for the first iteration, so if the user puts 1 + 2 + 3.
So

```
userInput[0] is 1
userInput[1] is +...
```

the first time that line will be triggered sum will be 1 + 2, and that's quite fine, but the second time, in the second +, you will sum i-1 (which is 2 and was in the total sum already) and i+1, that will be 3, so you are doing 1+2+2+3.

You need to understand why this is happening and think of another way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this is working for me

```
    var sum = 0
    readLine()?.split(" ")?.filter { it.toIntOrNull() != null }?.map { sum += it.toInt() }
    println(sum)
```